# How to delete a file on click of a span along with a confirmation to delete

Tags: php, unlink

I am generating a list of files from a folder on the server. Now I want to allow users to delete files from the server on click of the trash button.

I am not being able to do that neither know how to show a delete confirmation before delete.

**PHP**

```
for($index=0; $index<$count; $index++){
    $name = $filelist[$index];
    $extn = findexts($filelist[$index]);
    $size = human_filesize(filesize('./storage/'.$filelist[$index]));
    $thelist .= '<li><span class="type">'.$extn.'</span><span class="link"><a href=./storage/'.$name.'>'.$name.'</a></span><span class="size">'.$size.'</span><a href=delete.php?delete='.$name.'><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</li>';
}
```

**DELETE.PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    {
        unlink(__FILE__);
    }
?>
```

I am not sure how can I delete it.

Comment: Do **NOT** do this. If your browser decides to helpful and pre-fetch all links on the page, you'll be auto-nuking every single file you've put up a delete link for. This is a ludicrously BAD design. Never put a script that causes changes to your self on a "GET"-type url. And `__FILE__` will resolve to your `delete.php`, so you'll auto-nuke the very script you want to use to delete other files, anyways.

Comment: That will try and delete _the current file_!? O_o

Comment: @Marc B I am not sure what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: simple/stupid/dangerous: `unlink($_GET['delete'])`, but then you're STILL subject to unexpected mass deletion if something ever starts spidering this page. you need to have a proper confirmation page, with a full-blown roundtrip form submission using POST to confirm deletion, then do the deletion only after confirmation in a POST situation.

Comment: That means you are asking me to do a POST request?

Comment: @Marc B any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Link

```
<a href="storage/filename.ext" onClick="delfile()" id="test">Your File</a>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  function delfile(){
    var c   =document.getElementById("test").href;
    alert('are you sure you want to delete?');
    var filename = c.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    var redirect_path = 'delete.php?file_name='+filename;
    window.location.href=redirect_path;
 }
</script>
```

Now on delete php delete your file by getting file name.

PHP

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['file_name']){
    $filename=$_REQUEST['file_name'];
    unlink(filename,context);
}
?>
```

Comment: In my code how to get the id? as I am listing files directly from a folder and not from a database.

Comment: is there any information about image you are storing in database?

Comment: These are not images that am storing. These can be any files stored in a folder on the server. I am just listing the files in the page with the option of deleting them too.

Comment: I think you should look at my full code once to see my how am fetching the files. Check it here: http://pastebin.com/Bpbr6PW0